# Why do XKCD comics onebox?

Tags: discussion, chat, onebox

I'm curious as to why only XKCD comics are eligible for oneboxing in chat. XKCD is not the only webcomic out there, but as far as I know no other comics onebox by default.

Comment: Why is this question so heavily downvoted?

Comment: XKCD supplies the relevant OpenGraph meta data, as you can see when you use e.g. the [Facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fxkcd.com%2F2124%2F).

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted. It would be nice to know why the SE team originally decided to special-case XKCD.

Comment: @Randal'Thor "Non-significant" questions seem to get more hate on Meta for some reason. It's frustrating.

Comment: @Randal'Thor It was a VERY controversial question, it seems. When I checked the question when I got home after work, it had a score of -5. Right now I got 26 rep from it, which means at least 3 upvotes and 2 downvotes. I just thought it was an interesting question to ask.

Comment: "Why?" questions tend to get downvoted because "Why not?"

Comment: @Nzall I think it was on -7 when I saw it, meaning that I was the first upvote. Currently +17 / -10.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's not much to it. :) XKCD provides comic data in JSON that we can easily consume, it's a comic that gets quoted a bunch in chat, and at one point a developer cared enough to write-up the parser for the onebox.